# Which iPhone API should I be using for streaming audio?

Tags: iphone, audio, core-audio, voip

I'm looking to build a little toy app that is very similar to a voip application. One person would hold one iphone and talk to the other iphone. I don't want to use gamekit because it forces a p2p connection and does not work over 3g. I'm worrying about the server side of this later but just wanted to get started with the iPhone side of it. Which API to record audio in real time and which to play it back?

Answer (score 1):

Look to Audio Queue Services for capture and recording. You'd need to come up with a wire protocol to transmit the audio, but the tools to capture and playback or save on either side of the connection can be built using the queue services.